# How to make stenciljs component work with angular 2+ on Edge

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, polyfills, stenciljs

I'm importing custom element from Stenciljs into angular.
Everything work fine on the modern browser but doesn't work on Edge (nor IE11)
Is that something special I should do to make it work?

I'm using 
"@stencil/core": "1.1.9"
"@angular/core": "~7.2.13"
also tried with angular 8 but the same error happen.

I become those errors :
1. `ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property '$hostElement$' of undefined or null reference`
2. `SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '$flags$' of undefined or null reference`

It seems I have to do something on the angular side but I couldn't manage what.
I tried :
1. Using the angular polyfills
2. importing 'core-js/es7/reflect' into these polyfill
3. Add [document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) script tag into my index.html

*The stencil elements are working fine on Edge when I use them directly without angular*

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Stencil problem - have you tried to get an Angular app running in Edge without stencil components? If not, get that sorted first.

Comment: Please check the [stencil browser support](https://stenciljs.com/docs/browser-support), it seems that the stencil component support in Edge is currently in development, and the custom elements are not supported Microsoft Edge element.Besides, here is [an article](https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular) about using stencil with angular, you could check it.

Comment: @G.Tranter Everything that aren't coming from stencil works fine (e.g. normal angular component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have followed the integration process for Angular as mentioned here:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular

Then to support IE11 or Edge, try to include `applyPolyFills()`, if you haven't tried yet, when you invoke `defineCustomElements(window)` like so:

In your `main.ts` or where you have it included:

```
import {applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements} from 'path/to/stencil/loader';


applyPolyfills().then(() => {
   defineCustomElements(window);
});
```

I think it was not mentioned directly in *Framework Integration* documentation for Angular but it was mentioned in JavaScript integration section: 
https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer.  I wasn't importing the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` into the AppModule but directly in the module that was using my custom elements. (Funny, works fin with evergreen browser but not with edge).  And I confirm that I had to add the applyPolyfills().

Comment: Important to say. These answer solve my problem on an angular v.8 but not on angular v.9. I tried an `ng update` but still wasn't working. I had then to create a new project and migrate my old code into it. *I think ng update doens't change the polyfills*